# how to bypass style in element that is automatically applied through class?

Tags: css

I have got ul-li list in which there is a span element inside all li.
Currently there is a css class that is applied to that span element [or, so to say, the span elements inside all li] like:

```
.detail_div ul li span{
//some styles
}
```

Now for a particular span element inside, say, last li, i want to bypass the above given (default) css class and give different style. 
How can I achieve this?

Please help me out. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.detail_div ul li span {
   // Some Styles
}
.detail_div ul li:last-child span {
   // UNDO above styles
}
```

The second definition only matches the last `li`.

**Edit**: Or you can assign the list items you wish to unstyle a new class:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>Styled</span></li>
   <li class="unstyled"><span>Unstyled</span></li>
   <li><span>Styled</span></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.detail_div ul li span {
   // some styles
}
.detail_div ul li.unstyled span {
   // undo above styles
}
```

Or you can use the [nth-child pseudoclass](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works perfect for last li. But what if I want this done for some li in the middle?

Comment: for more complex calculations you can use :nth-child. Or you can give the li-items you wish to unstyle a new class.

Answer (score 3):

If just declaring the style again doesn't work. E.g.:

```
.detail_div ul li span{
  color: red;
}
```

Then put `!important` after the style. E.g.

```
.detail_div ul li span{
  color: red !important;
}
```

For the last item, add `:last-child`. E.g.

```
.detail_div ul li:last-child span{
  color: red !important;
}
```

And for something in the middle, use `:nth-child(number)`. E.g. second `LI`:

```
.detail_div ul li:nth-child(2) span{
  color: red !important;
}
```